# Bird's eye view perspective transformation from camera calibration opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, camera-calibration, perspective

I am trying to get the bird's eye view perspective transform from camera intrinsic, extrinsic matrices and distortion coefficients.

I tried using the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275877/opencv-get-perspective-matrix-from-translation-rotation) question.

The image used is the sample image left02.jpg from the opencv official github repo

[image: The image to be prospectively un-distored left02.jpg image from opencv sample images i.e get the bird's eye view of the image]

I calibrated the camera and found the intrinsic, extrinsic matrices and the distortion co-efficients.

I undistored the image and found the pose. To check if the params are right.

[image: Image after un-distortion and visualising pose]

The equations I used to find the perspective transformation matrix are (Refer the above link):

`Hr = K * R.inv() * K.inv()` where R is rotational matrix (from cv2.Rodrigues()) and K is obtained from cv2.getoptimalnewcameramatrix()

```
     [ 1  0  |         ]
Ht = [ 0  1  | -K*C/Cz ]
     [ 0  0  |         ]
```

Where `C=-R.inv()*T` Where T is translational vector from `cv2.solvePnP()`
and Cz is the 3rd component of the C vector

The required transformation is: `H = Ht * Hr`

The code I used to construct the above equation is:

```
K = newcameramtx # from cv2.getoptimalnewcameramatrix()
ret,rvec,tvec = cv2.solvePnP(world_points,corners2,K,dist) 
R,_ = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)
_,R_inv = cv2.invert(R)
_,K_inv = cv2.invert(K)
Hr = np.matmul(K,np.matmul(R_inv,K_inv))
C = np.matmul(-R_inv,tvec)
Cz = C[2]
temp_vector = np.matmul(-K,C/Cz)
Ht = np.identity(3)
for i,val in enumerate(temp_vector):
    Ht[i][2] = val
homography = np.matmul(Ht,Hr)
warped_img =cv2.warpPerspective(img,homography,(img.shape[1],img.shape[0]))
# where img is the above undistored image with visualized pose
```

The resulting warped image is not correct.
[image: With homographic matrix = Ht*Hr]

If I remove the translation from the homography by using the below code

```
homography = Hr.copy()
warped_img =cv2.warpPerspective(img,homography,(img.shape[1],img.shape[0]))
```

I am getting the following image
[image: With homographic matrix = Hr]

I think the above image shows that my rotational part is correct but my translation is wrong.

Since the translational matrix (Ht) is an augmented matrix am unsure whether my construction of the above matrix is correct.

I specifically want to figure out the bird's eye perspective transformation from the camera calibration.

So, How do I correct the above equations so that I am getting the perfect bird's eye view of the chessboard image

Could anyone also please explain the math on how the above equations for Ht and Hr are derived? I don't have much exposure to Linear algebra so these equations are not very obvious to me.

**UPDATE:**

```
homography = np.matmul(Ht,Hr)
warped_img =cv2.warpPerspective(img,homography,(img.shape[1],img.shape[0]),flags=cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)
```

## cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP flag gave me a different result

[image]

Still not the result I am looking for!

Comment: What is `R` in your code? The extrinsic from the calibration? What you need is the rotation between the camera at the current pose and the one that leads to the bird eye view. Have a look at this [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html).

Comment: R is the rotation matrix which I obtained from cv2.Rodrigues(). SolvePnP returns the rotation vector and it is converted to the rotation matrix by using the above function. And extrinsic matrix is [R|T]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to achieve is explained in the tutorial: [Demo 3: Homography from the camera displacement](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html#tutorial_homography_Demo3).

You have the current camera pose (rotation + translation), you can compute the desired camera pose that allows to view the chessboard from a bird eye view.

As the chessboard frame is different from the camera frame (see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#details) for the camera frame), the desired rotation for the camera pose that allows a bird eye view is:

[image]

Just follow the tutorial and you should get a homography matrix similar to:

```
H:
[0.935, -0.337, 40.383;
 -0.116, 0.729, 64.381;
 0.000408, -0.001299, 1]
```

With `warpPerspective`:

[image: Bird eye view]

Another example:

[image: Bird eye view 2]

As the chessboard is flat (for a generic scene a homography is valid only for a pure rotational camera movement), you can also play with the translation:

[image: Bird eye view 3]

**Edit:** the code derived from the tutorial

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/aruco.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

namespace
{
enum Pattern { CHESSBOARD, CIRCLES_GRID, ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID };

void calcChessboardCorners(Size boardSize, float squareSize, vector<Point3f>& corners, Pattern patternType = CHESSBOARD)
{
    corners.resize(0);

    switch (patternType)
    {
    case CHESSBOARD:
    case CIRCLES_GRID:
        //! [compute-chessboard-object-points]
        for( int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; j++ )
                //To try to center the chessboard frame, we substract the image size
                corners.push_back(Point3f(float((j-boardSize.width/2)*squareSize),
                                          float((i-boardSize.height/2)*squareSize), 0));
        //! [compute-chessboard-object-points]
        break;

    case ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID:
        for( int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; j++ )
                corners.push_back(Point3f(float((2*j + i % 2)*squareSize),
                                          float(i*squareSize), 0));
        break;

    default:
        CV_Error(Error::StsBadArg, "Unknown pattern type\n");
    }
}

void computeC2MC1(const Mat &R1, const Mat &tvec1, const Mat &R2, const Mat &tvec2,
                  Mat &R_1to2, Mat &tvec_1to2)
{
    //c2Mc1 = c2Mo * oMc1 = c2Mo * c1Mo.inv()
    R_1to2 = R2 * R1.t();
    tvec_1to2 = R2 * (-R1.t()*tvec1) + tvec2;
}
} //namespace

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("left02.jpg");
    Mat img_corners = img.clone(), img_pose = img.clone(), img_bird_eye_view = img.clone();
    vector<Point2f> corners;
    Size patternSize(9,6);
    bool found = findChessboardCorners(img, patternSize, corners);

    drawChessboardCorners(img_corners, patternSize, corners, found);
    imshow("Chessboard corners detection", img_corners);

    vector<Point3f> objectPoints;
    float squareSize = 2.5e-2;
    calcChessboardCorners(patternSize, squareSize, objectPoints);

    FileStorage fs("left_intrinsics.yml", FileStorage::READ);
    Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs;
    fs["camera_matrix"] >> cameraMatrix;
    fs["distortion_coefficients"] >> distCoeffs;

    Mat rvec, tvec;
    solvePnP(objectPoints, corners, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec);

    aruco::drawAxis(img_pose, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec, 2*squareSize);
    imshow("Pose", img_pose);

    Mat R_desired = (Mat_<double>(3,3) <<
                    0, 1, 0,
                    -1, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 1);
    Mat R;
    Rodrigues(rvec, R);
    Mat normal = (Mat_<double>(3,1) << 0, 0, 1);
    Mat normal1 = R*normal;
    Mat origin(3, 1, CV_64F, Scalar(0));
    Mat origin1 = R*origin + tvec;
    double d_inv1 = 1.0 / normal1.dot(origin1);
    Mat R_1to2, tvec_1to2;
    Mat tvec_desired = tvec.clone();

    computeC2MC1(R, tvec, R_desired, tvec_desired, R_1to2, tvec_1to2);
    Mat H = R_1to2 + d_inv1 * tvec_1to2*normal1.t();
    H = cameraMatrix * H * cameraMatrix.inv();
    H = H/H.at<double>(2,2);
    std::cout << "H:\n" << H << std::endl;

    warpPerspective(img_pose, img_bird_eye_view, H, img.size());
    Mat compare;
    hconcat(img_pose, img_bird_eye_view, compare);
    imshow("Bird eye view", compare);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I mean the tutorial is not still clear to me. The tutorial makes use of 2 chessboard locations. But what I am trying to do is inverse perspective transformation from the calculated camera intrinsic and extrinsics.

Comment: could you please give a sample code in python on how you did it? Thanks.

Comment: Extrinsic parameters give you the camera pose for the current chessboard position (rotation + translation). If you want to view the chessboard as a bird eye view, that means that the camera pose is changed in order to view the chessboard as a bird eye view. It is only possible because the chessboard is flat otherwise only rotation camera motion is valid for homography transformation. Sorry, I have only a C++ code that is more or less the same than the tutorial code.

Comment: An easier solution consists to just estimate the homography between the 4 current chessboard corners and the 4 desired chessboard corners in order to perform a "perspective correction".

Comment: Thanks for your response. I specifically want to find the solution from the camera extrinsic params. So your second recommendation doesn't suit the application. As you mentioned I tried out the tutorial But I am unable to reproduce your results. Specifically, R2 I gave as the matrix you gave (rotation for birds eye view.) How do i select the tvec2 ? I made tvec2 = tvec2 to give some results but it doesn't match your results. You mind sharing the C++ code which you used to get the results above? Thanks

Comment: I have updated with the code. Note that `H` was wrongly copy-pasted.

Comment: Thanks Now I am able to reproduce the results in python.

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji hello, would you pls consider posting your python solution to this in a gist or comment? thanks!

Comment: Hi, I was trying to reproduce these steps in Python, but I did not succeed. If someone can give me help, I posted a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/74837581/6509883

Answer (score 0):

I translated into python code

```
def computeC2MC1(R1, tvec1, R2, tvec2):
    R_1to2 = np.dot(R2, R1.T)
    tvec_1to2 = np.dot(R2, (-np.dot(R1.T, tvec1))) + tvec2
    return R_1to2, tvec_1to2

def cumputeH(K, R1, tvec1, R2, tvec2):
    normal = np.array([[0], [0], [1]], dtype=np.float64)
    normal1 = np.dot(R1, normal)
    origin = np.zeros((3, 1), dtype=np.float64)
    origin1 = np.dot(R1, origin) + tvec1
    d_inv1 = 1.0 / np.dot(normal1.T, origin1)
    R_1to2, tvec_1to2 = computeC2MC1(R1, tvec1, R2, tvec2)
    H = R_1to2 + d_inv1 * np.dot(tvec_1to2, normal1.T)
    H = np.dot(K, np.dot(H, np.linalg.inv(K)))
    H = H / H[2, 2]
    return H

R_desired, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(np.deg2rad([0, 0, 0]))

# newK, valid_pix_roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(K, dist, (w,h), alpha=0, newImgSize=(w,h))
tvec_desired = np.array([t[0], t[1], [50]], dtype=np.float64)
H = cumputeH(K, R, t, R_desired, tvec_desired)
img_dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, H, (w,h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

but there are some problems that I could not understand yet.

1. `tvec_desired` : if I copied tvec to tvec_desired , the rectified image looks too close. so I set it to 50 for now.
2. `R_desired` : if Rz is set to -90 or 90, the rectified image looks correct. but if set to 0, the calibration board appears stretched in the Y direction.

**thanks for any suggestions.**

[image: Rx=0, Ry=0, Rz=0]

[image: [Rx=0, Ry=0, Rz=-90]]