# Image perspective correction and measurement with a homography

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, homography

I want to calibrate a camera in order to make real world measurements of distance between features in an image. I'm using the OpenCV demo images for this example. *I'd like to know if what I'm doing is valid and/or if there is another/better way to go about it*. I could use a checkerboard of known pitch to calibrate my camera. But in this example the pose of the camera is as shown in the image below. So I can't just calculate px/mm to make my real world distance measurements, I need to correct for the pose first.

[image]

I find the chessboard corners and calibrate the camera with a call to OpenCV's calibrateCamera which gives the intrinsics, extrinsics and distortion parameters.

Now, I want to be able to make measurements with the camera in this same pose. As an example I'll try and measure between two corners on the image above. I want to do a perspective correction on the image so I can effectively get a birds eye view. I do this using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576087/birds-eye-view-perspective-transformation-from-camera-calibration-opencv-python/48602583#48602583). The idea is that the rotation for camera pose that gets a birds eye view of this image is a rotation on the z-axis. Below is the rotation matrix.

[image]

Then following this OpenCV homography [example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html#tutorial_homography_Demo3) I calculate the homography between the original view and my desired bird's eye view. If I do this on the image above I get an image that looks good, see below. Now that I have my perspective rectified image I find the corners again with findChessboardCorners and I calculate an average pixel distance between corners of ~36 pixels. If the distance between corners in rw units is 25mm I can say my px/mm scaling is 36/25 = 1.44 px/mm. Now for any image taken with the camera in this pose I can rectify the image and use this pixel scaling to measure distance between objects in the image. *Is there a better way to allow for real world distance measurements here?* *Is it possible to do this perspective correction for pixels only?* For example if I find the pixel locations of two corners in the original image can I apply the image rectification on the pixel coordinates only? Rather than on the entire image which can be computationally expensive? Just trying to deepen my understanding. Thanks

[image]

Some of my code

```
void MyCalibrateCamera(float squareSize, const std::string& imgPath, const Size& patternSize)
{

Mat img = imread(samples::findFile(imgPath));

Mat img_corners = img.clone(), img_pose = img.clone();
//! [find-chessboard-corners]
vector<Point2f> corners;
bool found = findChessboardCorners(img, patternSize, corners);
//! [find-chessboard-corners]

if (!found)
{
    cout << "Cannot find chessboard corners." << endl;
    return;
}

drawChessboardCorners(img_corners, patternSize, corners, found);
imshow("Chessboard corners detection", img_corners);
waitKey();
//! [compute-object-points]
vector<Point3f> objectPoints;
calcChessboardCorners(patternSize, squareSize, objectPoints);
vector<Point2f> objectPointsPlanar;
vector <vector <Point3f>> objectPointsArray;
vector <vector <Point2f>> imagePointsArray;

imagePointsArray.push_back(corners);
objectPointsArray.push_back(objectPoints);

Mat intrinsics;
Mat distortion;
vector <Mat> rotation;
vector <Mat> translation;
double RMSError = calibrateCamera(
    objectPointsArray,
    imagePointsArray,
    img.size(),
    intrinsics,
    distortion,
    rotation,
    translation,
    CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST |
    CALIB_FIX_K3 | CALIB_FIX_K4 | CALIB_FIX_K5 |
    CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO);
cout << "intrinsics: " << intrinsics << endl;
cout << "rotation: " << rotation.at(0) << endl;
cout << "translation: " << translation.at(0) << endl;
cout << "distortion: " << distortion << endl;

drawFrameAxes(img_pose, intrinsics, distortion, rotation.at(0), translation.at(0), 2 * squareSize);
imshow("FrameAxes", img_pose);
waitKey();

//todo: is this a valid px/mm measure?
float px_to_mm = intrinsics.at<double>(0, 0) / (translation.at(0).at<double>(2,0) * 1000);

//undistort the image
Mat imgUndistorted, map1, map2;
initUndistortRectifyMap(
    intrinsics,
    distortion,
    Mat(),
    getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(
        intrinsics,
        distortion,
        img.size(),
        1,
        img.size(),
        0),
    img.size(),
    CV_16SC2,
    map1,
    map2);
remap(
    img,
    imgUndistorted,
    map1,
    map2,
    INTER_LINEAR);
imshow("OrgImg", img);
waitKey();
imshow("UndistortedImg", imgUndistorted);
waitKey();

Mat img_bird_eye_view = img.clone();

//rectify
// https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html#tutorial_homography_Demo3
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576087/birds-eye-view-perspective-transformation-from-camera-calibration-opencv-python
//Get to a birds eye view, or -90 degrees z rotation
Mat rvec = rotation.at(0);
Mat tvec = translation.at(0);

//-90 degrees z. Required depends on the frame axes.
Mat R_desired = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
    0, 1, 0,
    -1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1);


//Get 3x3 rotation matrix from rotation vector
Mat R;
Rodrigues(rvec, R);
//compute the normal to the camera frame
Mat normal = (Mat_<double>(3, 1) << 0, 0, 1);
Mat normal1 = R * normal;
//compute d, distance . dot product between the normal and a point on the plane.
Mat origin(3, 1, CV_64F, Scalar(0));
Mat origin1 = R * origin + tvec;
double d_inv1 = 1.0 / normal1.dot(origin1);
//compute the homography to go from the camera view to the desired view
Mat R_1to2, tvec_1to2;
Mat tvec_desired = tvec.clone();
//get the displacement between our views
computeC2MC1(R, tvec, R_desired, tvec_desired, R_1to2, tvec_1to2);
//now calculate the euclidean homography
Mat H = R_1to2 + d_inv1 * tvec_1to2 * normal1.t();
//now the projective homography
H = intrinsics * H * intrinsics.inv();
H = H / H.at<double>(2, 2);
std::cout << "H:\n" << H << std::endl;
Mat imgToWarp = imgUndistorted.clone();
warpPerspective(imgToWarp, img_bird_eye_view, H, img.size());
Mat compare;
hconcat(imgToWarp, img_bird_eye_view, compare);
imshow("Bird eye view", compare);
waitKey();
...
```

Comment: I guess with the vanishing points of the 2 checkerboard axes you can find the rotation angles.

Comment: Yes, you can perform transformation of points. Use perspectiveTransform instead of warpPerspective,or multiply homogrneous cootdinates with the jomography matrix.

Comment: Your distance measurement will only be correct on the plane of the calibration pattern. If real objects are not on that plane (e.g. further away) your measurements wont work.

Comment: @Micka, yes you're right. I'll have a scaling error off of my calibration plane. I don't think there is anything I can do about that with just a single camera though? In my setup I should be able to have tight control of target placement. Thx